# I want to add a random generated password to my newly created Active Directory User

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I want to add a randomly generated password to my newly created Active Directory User. I have written a function to generate the password. I am using Powershell V2.0

I tried the below but did not help.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
[xml]$dataSource = Get-Content C:\Names1.xml

$name = Read-Host 'Please enter the table name : '

$user_logon = $dataSource.names.$name | ? { $_.Rule_Label -eq 'Regular service account (user logon)'}

$display_name = $dataSource.names.$name | ? { $_.Rule_Label -eq 'Regular service account (display name)'}

$pre_windows = $dataSource.names.$name | ? { $_.Rule_Label -eq 'Regular service account (pre-Windows 2000)'}

Function GET-Temppassword() { 
Param(
[int]$length=10, 
[string[]]$sourcedata 
)

For ($loop=1; $loop –le $length; $loop++) { 
    $TempPassword+=($sourcedata | GET-RANDOM)
    }

return $TempPassword
}


switch ($name) 
{ 
    DevTable{foreach($dataRecord in $dataSource) 
    {
    try     
    {
    $cn=$user_logon.Output_Value
    $sAMAccountName=$user_logon.Output_Value
    $givenName=$user_logon.Output_Value
    $sn=$user_logon.Output_Value 
    $displayName=$display_name.Output_Value 
    $userPrincipalName=$sAMAccountName + “@test.com”;

    $alphabet=$NULL;For ($a=65;$a –le 90;$a++) {$alphabet+=,[char][byte]$a }
    $TempPassword1 = GET-Temppassword –length 10 –sourcedata $alphabet


    New-ADUser $cn -SamAccountName $sAMAccountName -GivenName $givenName -Surname $sn -DisplayName $displayName -UserPrincipalName $userPrincipalName -AccountPassword $TempPassword1 -PasswordNeverExpires $true -Path "OU=Service,OU=Accounts,DC=xyz,DC=com"     

    set-aduser $cn -replace @{comment="xxyyzz"}
    set-aduser $cn -replace @{"account"=1}      

    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity xyz -Member $cn
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Service Accounts" -Member $cn

    write-host "New DevTable ADUser has been created!!!";
    }

    catch [Exception]
    {

        write-host "Error - Requested AD Service Account is already present...Please check & confirm " -foreground "red"
    }
    }   
    break;
    }

    default {"The table could not be determined!!!"}    

}   

[System.GC]::Collect()
```

Please have a look.Thanks.

Comment: How did it not help? Did it throw an error? Did it do nothing? Did it do the wrong thing? I'm not sure why you are using a switch in there? Where does $alphabet come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is written so that $sourceData can be a string like the following. If you really want to pass $sourcedata as an array of char remove the [char[]] cast from the function.

```
$sourcedata="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_-$"

Function GET-Temppassword() { 
  Param(
  [int]$length=10, 
  [string[]]$sourcedata 
  )

  -join ([char[]] $sourcedata | GET-RANDOM -count $length)
}

get-temppassword $sourceData 20
GVTXxF13ibnBK5AQOu-P
```